# Silverlight EAP vs APM to WCF Services

Tags: silverlight, asynchronous

I am building a Silverlight application that uses Web Services.

I have an ServiceAgent calls that is used to hide the proxy implementation from my ViewModels.

My question is which Asynchronous programming model is best used for Silverlight applications? That is, should I use Event base Async pattern (EAP) OR Async Programming Model (APM)?

Please let me know which has worked best for you in the past.

Comment: Please explain "the proxy implementation from my ViewModels"

Answer (score 1):

The rule of thumb is to implement the EAP when it is being used by UI code and the APM for back-end or library services.

I guess in your case, having events raised on the UI thread would be useful, so I would choose the EAP.

You might also want to consider using the new TAP: [Task-based Asynchronous Pattern](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=19957). This would make it easier to port to C#5 `async` when it is released later this year.

---

UPDATE:

I should have recommended using [TaskFactory.FromAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321543.aspx) since you are wrapping an existing APM.

Comment: I mostly agree with this.  However, I currently use the generated proxy and can use the ChannelFactory to easily use Begin and End methods.  Eventually i want to move away from the generated proxy and use ClientBase/ChannelFactory from my own proxy classes.  I think writting the Event base Asynch code would be much more involved.  Would you agree with this?

Comment: You're going to have to marshal back to the UI thread somewhere - the question is where? If you expose the EAP, you encapsulate the complexity behind your API and make it easier for your client ( the UI ). It would, as you say, be easier to expose the APM, but then your client will be more complex.

Comment: Unfortunatley i am currently limited to Silverlight 3, so this is not an option for me yet.